# How to use recursion to record all routes in a parent child hierarchy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, hierarchy

I am trying to go through a hierarchy dataframe and record every possible routes into another dataframe. These routes can have variable depth.

Original dataframe (df). The highest column means that the value in the parent column is not a child of any:

| parent | child | highest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 1 |
| b | c | 0 |
| b | d | 0 |
| d | e | 0 |

End goal dataframe:

| level 3 | level 2 | level 1 | level 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |  |
| a | b | d | e |

This what I currently have

```
def search(parent):
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        if(df.iloc[i,0] == parent):
            search(df.iloc[i,1])

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if(df.iloc[i,2] == 1):
        search(df.iloc[i,0])
```

I am able to go through the hierarchy but I do not know how to save it in the format I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to solve the problem. Note if you use `networkx` you don't need the `highest` columns. The main function to find all paths is [`all_simple_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html)

```
# Python env: pip install networkx
# Anaconda env: conda install networkx
import networkx as nx

# Create network from your dataframe
#G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent', target='child',
#                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# For older versions of networkx
G = nx.DiGraph()
for _, (source, target) in df[['parent', 'child']].iterrows():
    G.add_edge(source, target)

# Find roots of your graph (a root is a node with no input)
roots = [node for node, degree in G.in_degree() if degree == 0]

# Find leaves of your graph (a leaf is a node with no output)
leaves = [node for node, degree in G.out_degree() if degree == 0]

# Find all paths
paths = []
for root in roots:
  for leaf in leaves:
    for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaf):
        paths.append(path)

# Create a new dataframe
out = pd.DataFrame(paths).fillna('')
out.columns = reversed(out.add_prefix('level ').columns)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  level 3 level 2 level 1 level 0
0       a       b       c        
1       a       b       d       e
```

Comment: I have gotten this error:
module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_pandas_edgelist'

I believe this is due to the version of the networkx installed in my computer, which is 1.11. And I am unable to update as the machine that is used to run the script is blocked from the internet. Is there any alternatives methods?

Comment: @Denzyl You can create an empty graph `G = nx.DiGraph()` then use [`G.add_edges_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edges_from.html)

Comment: @Denzyl. I updated my answer  for use to your old version. The solution of the comment above could work too.

Comment: I am now getting a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) error at the ```roots = [node for node, degree in G.in_degree() if degree == 0]```

Comment: @Denzyl. replace `G.in_degree()` by `G.in_degree_iter()`. Does it work? Same for `out_degree`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the networkx library. You do not need the `highest` column. It can be deduced from the graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
df = pd.DataFrame([ \
        ('a',   'b',    1), \
        ('b',   'c',    0), \
        ('b',   'd',    0), \
        ('d',   'e',    0)], columns=['parent', 'child', 'highest'])

parents = df.parent.values
childs = df.child

G = nx.DiGraph()
for i in range(len(parents)):
    parent = parents[i]
    child = childs[i]

    if not parent in G.nodes:
        G.add_node(parent)

    if not child in G.nodes:
        G.add_node(child)

    G.add_edge(parent, child)

roots = [node for node in G.nodes if G.in_degree(node) == 0]
root = roots[0]

leaves = [node for node in G.nodes if G.out_degree(node) == 0]

all_paths = [list(nx.simple_paths.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaf)) for leaf in leaves]

# Flatten
all_paths = [tuple(path) for paths in all_paths for path in paths]

paths_df = pd.DataFrame(all_paths)
```

I will leave for you to rename the columns as per your liking.