# how data group by of recursive data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, recursion, networkx

I have a data frame that is in recursive type. I want to multiply quantity that is related to the same parent and then sums the resultant quantity.
example:

```
ParentCode ItemCode  Qty  ResultantQty
         A        B    2             2
         B        C    1             2
         Z        Y    3             3
         Y        C    4            12
```

I want resultant quantity ((2*1)+(3*4)) in data frame form.
I have a large dataset.

What I have try so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

data = pd.DataFrame({'ParentCode': ['A', 'B', 'Z', 'Y'],
                     'ItemCode': ['B', 'C', 'Y', 'C'],
                     'Qty': [2, 1, 3, 4]})

leaves = set(data.ItemCode).difference(data.ParentCode)

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, 'ParentCode', 'ItemCode', 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())

ancestors = { n: nx.algorithms.dag.ancestors(g, n) for n in leaves } 

a=(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ancestors, orient='index')
               .rename(lambda x: 'ParentCode_{}'.format(x+1), axis=1)
               .rename_axis('ItemCode')
               .fillna(''))
```

Comment: import networkx as nx

leaves = set(data.ItemCode).difference(data.ParentCode)
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, 'ParentCode', 'ItemCode', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
ancestors = {
    n: nx.algorithms.dag.ancestors(g, n) for n in leaves
}

a=(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ancestors, orient='index')
   .rename(lambda x: 'ParentCode_{}'.format(x+1), axis=1)
   .rename_axis('ItemCode')
   .fillna(''))

Comment: I did it by using networkx but it gave not accurate output

Comment: write your code in https://gist.github.com/ and then give the link to that Gist

Comment: parent has one child which means data in for of A>B>C and Z>Y>C

Comment: No, I want the resultant quantity on respective rows in the dataframe and process further.

Comment: @Corralien Thank you so much actually I am new in the stack overflow.

Comment: I just updated one column of the resultant quantity.

Comment: As a start point, you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69342516/15239951)

Answer (score 1):

Based from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69342516/15239951):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ParentCode': ['A', 'B', 'Z', 'Y'],
                     'ItemCode': ['B', 'C', 'Y', 'C'],
                     'Qty': [2, 1, 3, 4]})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source='ParentCode', target='ItemCode',
                            edge_attr='Qty', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

roots = [node for node, degree in G.in_degree() if degree == 0]
leaves = [node for node, degree in G.out_degree() if degree == 0]

data2 = []
for root in roots:
    for leaf in leaves:
        paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaf)
        n = 1
        for edge in list(*map(nx.utils.pairwise, paths)):
            n *= G.edges[edge]['Qty']
            data2.append((edge[0], edge[1], n))

data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['ParentCode', 'ItemCode', 'ResultantQty'])
out = data.merge(data2, on=['ParentCode', 'ItemCode'])
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
  ParentCode ItemCode  Qty  ResultantQty
0          A        B    2             2
1          B        C    1             2
2          Z        Y    3             3
3          Y        C    4            12
```