# How to get threads/conversations from reply ids (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, twitter, tree

I'm a relative newbie with python and I'm trying to reconstruct conversations/threads from a dataframe with a list of IDs.

I currently have a pandas dataframe of tweets / reddit posts which have roughly the following format:

| id | text | parent_id | replies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | blah blah | _ post _ | id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, id7 |
| id2 | blah blah | id1 | id4, id5, id6, id7 |
| id3 | blah blah | id1 |  |
| id4 | blah blah | id2 | id6, id7 |
| id5 | blah blah | id2 |  |
| id6 | blah blah | id4 | id7 |
| id7 | blah blah | id6 |  |

My goal is to separate the data into threads/conversations based on the ids. This would mean, from the above example, getting the following sequences as the output:

[id1, id2, id4, id6],

[id1, id2, id4, id7],

[id1, id2, id5], &

[id1, id3].

Having these lists would then enable me to look at threads in their entirety. Currently my code is very convoluted and looks something like this:

```
out_list = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    id_ = row["id"]
    # create our output file 
    sequence = [id_]
    replies = list(row['replies'])
    # creates a new dataframe from the replies to the topline comment in question
    reply_df= df.loc[df['id'].isin(replies)]
    reply_df = reply_df[reply_df.Parent_id2 == id_]
    #check if ends at topline
    if reply_df.empty == False:
        
        def turn_recursion(df, reply_df):
            for j, row_ in reply_df.iterrows():
                replies_2 = reply_df.loc[j, 'replies']
                id_2 = row_["id"]

                reply_df2 =  df.loc[df['id'].isin(replies_2)]
                reply_df2 = reply_df2[reply_df2.Parent_id2 == id_2]

                nonlocal sequence
                nonlocal out_list
                            
                if reply_df2.empty == False:
                    sequence.append(id_2)
                    return(turn_recursion(df, reply_df2))
                
                else:
                    sequence.append(id_2)
                    out_list.append(sequence)
        
        turn_recursion(test2, reply_df)
    else:
        out_list.append(sequence)
```

This is currently giving me semi-accurate results but instead of getting: [[id1, id2, id4, id6],[id1, id2, id4, id7]], I get: [id1, id2, id4, id6, id7].

I realise I'm probably being a bit dim and that there is a simple solution, but for the life of me, I can't seem to figure out a way of doing this so that it works properly and for any thread length.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions. :)

Comment: Use `networkx` to solve this kind of problem. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69342255/15239951) as a start point. I will answered tomorrow if I can.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - networkx already looks like a very promising starting place for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `networkx` to achieve what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

# Build graph from pandas
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent_id', target='id', 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# Find leaves (id3, id5, id7)
leaves = [node for node, degree in G.out_degree() if degree == 0]

# Enumerate all possible paths
for node in df['id']:
    for leaf in leaves:
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, node, leaf):
            data[node].append(path)
```

Output:

```
>>> data
defaultdict(list,
            {'id1': [['id1', 'id3'],
              ['id1', 'id2', 'id5'],
              ['id1', 'id2', 'id4', 'id6', 'id7']],
             'id2': [['id2', 'id5'], ['id2', 'id4', 'id6', 'id7']],
             'id4': [['id4', 'id6', 'id7']],
             'id6': [['id6', 'id7']]})
```

If you want to merge the dictionary to your dataframe:

```
df['replies'] = df['id'].map(data)
print(df)

# Output:
    id       text parent_id                                            replies
0  id1  blah blah  _ post _  [[id1, id3], [id1, id2, id5], [id1, id2, id4, ...
1  id2  blah blah       id1                 [[id2, id5], [id2, id4, id6, id7]]
2  id3  blah blah       id1                                                 []
3  id4  blah blah       id2                                  [[id4, id6, id7]]
4  id5  blah blah       id2                                                 []
5  id6  blah blah       id4                                       [[id6, id7]]
6  id7  blah blah       id6                                                 []
```

Now you can explode your dataframe:

```
df = df.explode('replies')
print(df)

# Output:
    id       text parent_id                    replies
0  id1  blah blah  _ post _                 [id1, id3]
0  id1  blah blah  _ post _            [id1, id2, id5]
0  id1  blah blah  _ post _  [id1, id2, id4, id6, id7]
1  id2  blah blah       id1                 [id2, id5]
1  id2  blah blah       id1       [id2, id4, id6, id7]
2  id3  blah blah       id1                        NaN
3  id4  blah blah       id2            [id4, id6, id7]
4  id5  blah blah       id2                        NaN
5  id6  blah blah       id4                 [id6, id7]
6  id7  blah blah       id6                        NaN
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem? Let me know if the exit is not suitable. It is a bit unclear for me.

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem clearly and succinctly, thank you so much. (I'm new to stackoverflow so my upvote has yet to be counted)