# How to translate a dataframe with parent / child hierarchy into a dataframe with parent name in separate columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have dataframe for Location information which contains `Name`, `Code`, `Parent` and `Name` field contains all `Country`, `State`, `District`, `Taluk` names in single field.

[image]

I would like to view in below format.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69342255/15239951), you can use `networkx` package to accomplish what you want. The only difference here is the graph is inverted so the root (Parent=NaN) is a leave.

```
# Python env: pip install networkx
# Anaconda env: conda install networkx
import networkx as nx

# Create network from your dataframe
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Code', target='Parent',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# Here, roots are the leaves of your graph
leaves = [node for node, degree in G.out_degree() if degree == 0]

# Find all paths
paths = []
for node in df['Code']:
    for leaf in leaves:
        path = nx.all_simple_paths(G, node, leaf)
        paths.append(list(reversed(*path))[1:]) # [1:] to remove nan

# Build your new columns
names = df.set_index('Code')['Name'].to_dict()
cols = ['Country', 'State', 'District', 'Taluk']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(paths, index=df.index, columns=cols).replace(names)

# Join your 2 dataframes
df = df.join(df1).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Name    Code  Parent Country      State   District      Taluk
0      India      IN           India                                 
1  Karnataka   IN_KA      IN   India  Karnataka                      
2  Bangalore  KA_BNG   IN_KA   India  Karnataka  Bangalore           
3  Yelahanka  KA_YLH  KA_BNG   India  Karnataka  Bangalore  Yelahanka
```

Comment: I was facing some issues while applying to real data and figuring out. Thanks for the help. Will update if success.