# how to unravel table based on parent id in category name table using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert following nested table:

[image: nested table]

into this flat table:

[image]

I would like to code be written in python pandas.

Could you help with this?

Comment: Please provide your input data as plain text.

Comment: I'm not really seeing the pattern here between the split name column in the first and second image. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I think you have the same question that https://stackoverflow.com/q/69759278/15239951