# Python - Parent-Child Hierarchy Recursive Structure

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, networkx, hierarchical-data

I am trying to form a parent to child relationship combination using data available in my pandas dataframe.

Data Example:

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| B | D |
| B | C |
| C | D |

Expected chain results:

A|B

A|C

A|B|D

A|B|C

A|C|D

A|B|C|D

I tried something with networkx package to trace out the trees. I am partially successful. But it misses some of the hierarchies shown in the expected result.

Like, if the child has sub-nodes associated with it, it's not appearing as separate result.

For example, in the above data B is a child to A and has D & C are childs of B.

While applying my code, it shows A|B|D & A|B|C|D alone.

**A|B is skipped as B has childs (C & D )**

**A|B|C is skipped as B has childs (C & D ) and subsequently C also has child (D)**

**A|C is skipped as C has child (D)**

I used the code shown in below link

[How to use recursion to record all routes in a parent child hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69342255/how-to-use-recursion-to-record-all-routes-in-a-parent-child-hierarchy)

Comment: [*"Need help"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) is not a suitable question here. Please show your attempt, and where things are not going as expected, and what you have done to research and debug.

Comment: @trincot: I've added whatever I tried

Comment: This is a network problem, read on [networkx](https://networkx.org/) as you already tagged. You can think of your data as a (collection of) trees, then find all the leaves, and path to the tree roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution with [`all_simple_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths) :

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, # or pd.read_csv("file.csv")
    source="parent", target="child", create_using=nx.DiGraph)

root = next(nx.topological_sort(G))

out = (
    pd.Series(
        [
            list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, c)) for c in df["child"]
        ]
    ).explode().sort_values(key=lambda s: s.str.len())
    .drop_duplicates().str.join("|").to_frame("paths")
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

     paths
0      A|B
1      A|C
1    A|B|C
2    A|B|D
2    A|C|D
2  A|B|C|D
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your answer. I am able to get the tree structure as expected now. Once again, thanks for your guidance.